# How do I import a Dataset that contains lists?

Tags: import, dataset, parsing

The very first example in the Dataset documentation is the following:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
<|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

The third column of this dataset contains Lists. 
I would like to create a file that I can read (e.g. using `SemanticImport`) and that will parsed into this format.

An example for a String that does not work:

```
datatest = SemanticImportString["a\tb\tc\1\tx\t{1}\n"]
```

Here the column labeled "c" becomes the String `"{1}"`.

Similarly,

```
datatest = SemanticImportString["a\tb\tc\n1\tx\t{1}\n", {"String", "String", "List"}]
```

puts the String `"{1}"` into a List: `{"{1}"}`.

Since the Dataset format is touted as a way to work with hierarchical data sets I assume there must be some convenient way to actually read in a hierarchical data set? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell you want `{1}` in your string to be read as a *Mathematica* expression, i.e. read as a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html).  I believe you may therefore use the type `"Expression"`:

```
SemanticImportString["a\tb\tc\n1\tx\t{1}\n", {"String", "String", "Expression"}]
```